# Regex split and concatenate path base and pattern with filename deleting part of path between them

Tags: regex, path

I have an URL like this:

a) `<a href=\"http://example.com/path-pattern-to-match/subPath/onemoreSubpath/arbitrary-number-of-subpaths/someArticle1\">`

or:

b) `<a href=\"http://example.com/path-pattern-to-match/someArticle2\">`

I need to split path pattern with its base URL, start of `<a>` tag and concatenate it with Iits `someArticle`. Everything in between needs to be deleted.

Case 'b' remains untouched. Case 'a' needs to become:

`<a href=\"http://example.com/path-pattern-to-match/someArticle1\">`

Please answer with a RegEx, that is what I need. Other solutions could be interesting if well explained, using Perl or a bash script, but please avoid to suggest some programming module or function to parse it only to say that RegEx is not the best solution and without any real one solution.

PS: I need to parse a non multiline file. 
`someArticle` is variable.

Comment: Take a look here: _https://regex101.com/r/fU9uI0/1_

Comment: Hi @WashingtonGuedes thank's Your solution is valid for a multiline file, but I have to parse an SQL file in this case the regEx fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have look-behind support, use

```
(?<=<a href=\\"http:\/\/example\.com\/path-pattern-to-match\/)(?:[^\/]+\/)*([^\/>"]*)(?=\\">)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/gT7yK4/3)

**EXPLANATION**

- `(?<=<a href=\\"http:\/\/example\.com\/path-pattern-to-match\/)` - a fixed width lookbehind making sure we have `<a href=\"http://example.com/path-pattern-to-match/` literal text in front of...
- `(?:[^\/]+\/)*` - 0 or more sequences of 1 or more characters other than `/` (`[^\/]+`) followed with a literal `/` (i.e. subpaths)
- `([^\/>"]*)` - A capturing group that matches our keyword "someArticle" (0 or more characters other than `"`, `>`, or `/`.
- `(?=\\">)` - A positive lookahead checking if there is a `\">` right after the preceding subpattern.

Using the `$1` replacement string, you can remove the subpaths and keep the "someArticle" part.

Comment: Hi @stribizhev I have edited my question, I'm sorry about, there was an  unclear detail: someArticle is always different and I need to extract it to concatenate with the pattern and delete all in between, your RegEx work fine matching the right <a> tags but I'm unable to extract someArticle.

Comment: I suggest rearranging the round brackets (i.e. set the capturing group) around the "someArticle" that will be captured with the `[^>]*` pattern (*0 or more characters other than `>`*). I see the look-behind is not working for you, is it?

Comment: Look-behind is working. Your edit needs an open brackets at the beginning of the expression look here, Your updated demo:  https://regex101.com/r/gT7yK4/1 Extract someArticle only when there aren't subpaths after the pattern.

Comment: Aha, so if there are subpaths, you do not want to get it, right? Check [this one: `<a href=\\"http:\/\/example\.com\/path-pattern-to-match\/([^\/>]*)\\">`](https://regex101.com/r/gT7yK4/2).

Comment: I need to delete all the possible subpaths between base URL, path pattern and everything after the last / so: `<a href=\"http://example.com/path-pattern-to-match/someArticleOne\"> <a href=\"http://example.com/path-pattern-to-match/subPath/onemoreSubpath/arbitrary-number-of-subpaths/someArticleTwo\">` become: `<a href=\"http://example.com/path-pattern-to-match/someArticlePne\"> <a href=\"http://example.com/path-pattern-to-match/someArticleTwo\">`

Comment: I cannot understand how you can match `someArticle` if it is always different? What is the requirement? A CaMeL word? A string of characters other than ``\`` and space? As the subpath is also unknown, where is the boundary? Or is it only `1` that changes in `someArticle1` (the last digit only)? Please be specific.

Comment: someArticle could be a string of characters other than `\"`

Comment: Yes! That's it! Thank you very much @stribizhev! If you would edit your answer I'll could choose it as correct.

Comment: Done. I hope it will be very useful to you :)